# Installing MySQL

Tags: macos, mysql

I try to install MySQL on my Mac but I didn't succeeded at opening the .pkg file. Probably I should use the installer in application/utilities but I can't find it either.

Comment: WHere di you get the .pkg file from. Double clicking on it in finder should work

Comment: This is a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

why not install MAMP? It installs mysql for you.

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: @Dylan beat me by 21 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

An easier option worth considering is to just go with mamp. It installs everything you need to setup a development environment on a mac.

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is, but have you [downloaded the installer packages from MySQL.com?](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

They have worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

you can install BREW http://brew.sh/

This is an equivalent to "apt-get" on Debian, or yum on Redhat/Centos. Once installed you can try:

```
brew install mysql
```